# How to get applescript to delete files which the Finder requires a password to delete

Tags: applescript, macos

I have the following (snippet of) code:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set theFolders to every folder of theHeadFolderPath
    <repeat loop to select the element of theFolders to put into earliestFolder>
     delete earliestFolder
end tell
```

This works just fine, except that `earliestFolder` happens to contain a copy of my home library folder (among other things) and deep inside Containers is a bunch of AutoSave documents from TextEdit.  These files are not locked, but their permissions only give me read-only access, and System Events seems incapable of getting them to delete.  If I command-option-backspace in the Finder, I'm asked for my password, and they are deleted.

I gotta think that these are **not** the only files in my library folder with such permissions, but whatever, for some reason the Mac is being particularly precious about them.

I want these files deleted from the disk, not put in the Trash.

How can I get them deleted from within applescript?  I'd really rather not use `do shell script` if I can help it.

Many thanks!